# Facebook login checks user in facebook app only once in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-login

I faced an authorization issue while integrating facebook login in my app in iOS 10.

I have 2 test facebook accounts. In my app I use facebook app to log in. Than I login in facebook app with different username. After that I log out from my app and try to login with new username with help of facebook app.

In iOS 11 it works well, but in iOS 10 it logs me in with the first facebook username. Not even check if it has changed. 
I have this command executed when tapping login button:

```
FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [loginManager logOut];
```

How to fix this?

UPDATE:

tried this:

```
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me/permissions" parameters:nil
                                           HTTPMethod:@"DELETE"] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            // ...
        }];
```

and this:

```
[FBSDKProfile enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange:YES];
```

Doesn't help

Comment: You are only allowed to have one Facebook account

Comment: You mean allowed by facebook? What if two people use the same device and apps installed on it?

Comment: I mean Facebook doesn't allow you to have two Facebook accounts.

Comment: This is answer on some other question. And is not related to mine. I want customers of app I develop to be able to log in with multiple accounts. Because as I said before two people could use the same device. For example parent and kid.